# Get Next Char/String After A Particular String

Tags: java, string

I want to get Next Characters in a given para of string as whenever that word is repeated,the next characters of string should print, let's say upto 6 more characters to fetch the desired string after the given word.

Ex. Rock

I tried with this,but not getting the desired output.

```
String example = "Hi man check rock,let's go on together to the sight of rock now Print upto 6 char";
        System.out.println(example.substring(example.indexOf("rock") + 5));
```

Comment: What is your expected output and which output do you get?

Answer (score 3):

You can select the begin and end with substring. Try this:

```
int stringindex = example.indexOf("rock");   //Save the index to a variable so you don't have to call the indexOf method twice. 
int stringlength = "rock".length();
example.substring(stringindex + stringlength, stringindex + stringlength + 5); //Select next 5 characters from the index of rock.
```

Comment: it's printing rock, and I wanted the output to print as ",let's now Pr" as up to 6 characters in the given string.

Comment: Edited it. This should work. You can change 5 with whatever length you want.

Comment: Thanks for checking, But it shouldn't print rock..It should print next characters after that and that too, only 6 characters after it.

Comment: That Worked..But how to also find the next word in the para and do the same with it? Also, please let me know how you come up with it..I want to emphasize on how you come up with it!☺️

Comment: You should check the documentation and the API. Then learn how to use `indexOf()` and `substring()`.

Comment: Not coming up for Next Words. in the para mentioned. Should print up as ",let's now Pr" total 6 characters after rock is found, including space.

Comment: Also, can we trim the spaces by using Regex here or simple trim will work?

Comment: A simple trim would work. If you wan't to know what a method does just google it. Java has everything documented.

Answer (score 1):

Solution : Assuming to print only characters not words and also counting space as

String example = "Hi man check rock,let's go on together to the sight of rock now Print upto 6 char";

Ans: System.out.println(Str.substring(Str.lastIndexOf("rock")+"rock".length(),Str.lastIndexOf("rock")+"rock".length()+6));

output :  now P (Total six characters counting 2 spaces and 4 characters ).

Please let me know for any improvements

Update:

Please find below code:
code initially captures the first index and loops through the string for other occurences and build's the result string in the loop.

```
import java.io.*;
public class Test {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      String Str = "Hi man check rock,let's go on together to the sight of rock now Print upto 6 char";
    String keyword = "rock";
    String result="";

    int index = Str.indexOf(keyword);
    while (index >=0){
        System.out.println("Index : "+index);
        result+=Str.substring(index+keyword.length(),index+keyword.length()+6);
        index = Str.indexOf(keyword, index+keyword.length())   ;
   }
   System.out.println(result);
   }
}
```

Comment: please check my desired output in Luud comments. It should come first with ",let's " and then in same line, " now P" with spaces.. Will look together as ",let's  now P". N.B: mind the two spaces..Now total length will be 12 here.

Answer (score 0):

```
String example = "Hi man check rock,let's go on together to the sight of rock now Print upto 6 char";
System.out.println(example.substring(example.indexOf("rock")+4, example.indexOf("rock") + 11));
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting Next String/word After A Particular String ( ex:rock) using regex

```
String stringToSearch = "Hi man check rock,let's go on together to the sight of rock now rock again Print upto 6 char";
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("rock[,\\s][\\w]+");
Matcher m = p1.matcher(stringToSearch);

Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("[,\\s]");
while (m.find())
{
    String[] items = p2.split(m.group());
    if(items.length < 2 )
       break;
    System.out.println(items[1]);   
}
```

Otuput:
let
now
again